# a Java application works fine on Eclipse but it doesn't work properly after being deployed as a runnable jar

Tags: java, jar, inputstream

Like the tile said, my Java application doesn't work as it works fine while developing on Eclipse.

I finished to build and test my application on Eclipse. It works fine as I expected. I needed to deploy it as a runnable jar so that my client can't use it on their system. I made it a runnable jar through exporting it on Eclipse.
When I run the runnable jar, the application starts to work fine for a while and stops on file reading. I haven't had any problem with it on the same code on Eclipse.

The source snippet that seems not to work is the following.

```
            sfis = new SmbFileInputStream(sFile);
            in = new BufferedInputStream(sfis);

            byte buf[] = new byte[(int)sFile.length()];
            int pos = 0;
            int size = 10;
            int temp;

            while((size=in.read(buf, pos, size)) > 0){
                pos += size; 
                temp = buf.length - pos;
                if(temp < 10){
                    size = temp;
                }
            }
```

On Eclipse it doesn't cause any problem. It perfectly reads data from SMB connection and finishes its job. But from the jar application, it seems to stop reading from inputstream inside while loop at some point. 
This is a very strange case that I have never experienced before. And I can't find any solution for this.

Is this because of my code or the jar file that might be wrongly made by Eclipse?

---------- additional info -------------------

With a big help from Edmondo1984, I find out where the jar program stops.
When it goes to inputstream from SmbFile, a new thread jcifs.util.transport.Transport is created and the thread is simply blocked and the application creates another jcifs.util.transport.Transport, and so on. After creating 8 or 9 jcifs.util.transport.Transport thread, it is being stuck and doing nothing.

The same code, the same jcifs library. But works differently between running on Eclipse and on local machine as a runnable jar. 
I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Eclipse might be failing to put the right jars in your "packaged jar" , but this normally results in Classloading errors. Are you testing on the same file?

Comment: You have to give yourself some visible indicator on what is going on. Ie in a try catch output some kind of meaning ful message on what has happened. An error message above would be useful to debug what is going on.

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Like you said, if Eclipse failed to add some libraries needed for the application, it won't start. But it starts run. Oh yeah I am testing the same file.

Comment: @Davos555 As I explained, it works fine on Eclipse. No errors are thrown. I actually prefer to have the application made errors. And those codes are inside of catch block. All I did last time was that I put sysout inside while loop. It prints out for a while and gets slow. And then it stops. The application is still running, but no errors.

Comment: Can you attach Jconsole to your application when it gets stucked so you can see where the application is hanging?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 I tried to attach Jconsole to it. But What factor should I see? CPU usage is dropped to below 0.2 and sometimes 0.0. It happens inside loop.

Comment: You can see if there are deadlocks and if your application is not multi-threaded where the the main thread is currently at. Can you see the stacktrace?

Comment: Could it be that when starting the runnable jar, a different version of java is used? Add `System.out.println(System.getProperties().toString().replaceAll(", ", "\n"));` somewhere in your code and compare the results.

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Thanks for this tip. I can see where the main thread is stuck. The first two traces as follows java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
jcifs.util.transport.Transport.connect(Transport.java:168)c
   - locked jcifs.smb.SmbTransport@39d325
I guess the problem is jcifs library. But still can't understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 2):

The return value for "there is nothing more on the stream" is `-1` (see [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29)).

Imagine what happens if you try to `in.read(buf, pos, size)` but the underlying is still not available. Then the call immediately returns with a return value  of `0` (zero). This way, the loop condition evaluates to false and the loop is exited. So I think you should compare against `!= -1`.

Another possible issue: You may also consider what happens if `size = 0` (e.g. due to above scenario) and `temp >= 10`. Because you directly feed back the value of `size` to `in.read(buf, pos, size)` as the maximum number of bytes to read, you could end up in an infinite loop, assuming you have already corrected the comparison to `!= -1`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but your solution doesn't work either. As I explained, it works fine on Eclipse. If what you said were a real problem, the application wouldn't work on Eclipse either.

Comment: As long as `read()` always returns with at least one byte read (which is definitely not guaranteed), you won't run into any trouble. I see that the assumptions of your code and the docs do not match. From this, I was speculating what could happen if the assumptions are not met (described above). As Tiago also pointed out in his answer, there might be different runtime behaviour between Eclipse and the JAR.

Answer (score 1):

When meddling with streams, those kind of behaviors are frequent. Small algorithmic incorrections may cause different symptoms in different environments.

You could print "debug" information to the console to better understand where and why is your code stalling. I'm pretty sure its on the read method.

There are several things wrong with your code, the most notorious is the block:

```
temp = buf.length - pos;
if(temp < 10){
  size = temp;
}
```

Why? When there are 10 or less bytes left you'll try to read them in the next read(), otherwise you'll potentially try to read too much (the whole file size again). Running in Eclipse, the file is probably being read in the first read(), out of Eclipse apparently not.
Try to change your code to something like this:

```
FileInputStream sfis = new FileInputStream(sFile);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte buf[] = new byte[4096];
int read = sfis.read(buf);
while(read>0){
  baos.write(buf, 0, read);
  read = sfis.read(buf);
}
sfis.close();
```

Also consider to use [Apache's Java IO utilities](http://commons.apache.org/io/) code instead of always writing this type of code. IO in Java needs a lot of boilerplate, and a good programmer has better things to do.

On a side-note: reading a file to memory is usually a bad idea. Unless you're going to transform its data as a whole in some way, streaming is always better. I don't know what is your program for but please keep this in mind: what happens if you try to read a 10GB file? or several?

Happy coding,

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason why I did that on the parts your mentioned is to make file reading a bit faster. I understand that doesn't do much, but the application reads lots of file usually less than 30 MB so I needed that kind of algorithm. As for your code, I also tried it, but the same thing happens and also this time it happens earlier than before.

Answer (score 0):

Java is capital letter sensitive in evry way. For example if you have file named image.PNG and in your code you set location to "/image.png" (instead of "/image.PNG") it will work fine in eclipse, but after exporting runnable jar file java VM will be not able to find that file.